# Mergin two arrays but keep indexes

Tags: php, arrays

So I have these two arrays that I need to merge into one and keep the indexes. I tried different things like `array_merge`, `array_merge_recursive`, etc but I couldn't figure it out.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Peter"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Josh"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Jasper"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "18"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "25"
}
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["age"]=>
    int(18)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Josh"
    ["age"]=>
    int(19)
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: A foreach or for loop would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Of course I made an effort and I have explained what I have tried. Why do you assume that I haven't and vote me down for no reason? :(

Comment: Okay I did it with for loop. Thanks @aynber for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'Peter', 1 => 'Josh', 2 => 'Jasper');
$array2 = array(0 => '18', 1 => '19', 2 => '25');
for($i = 0; $i<count($array1); $i++){
   $newArray[] = array("name" => $array1[$i], "age" => $array2[$i]);
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Yeah I came up with almost the same solution after aynber gave me a heads up in the comments above. Thank you dude! I will mark your response as helpful either way :)

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've used before as more reusable decision in case you want to add for example not only Name, Age, but Email or something else later.

Posting below code with explained comments.

```
<?php

// Array containing names
$namesArr = array(
    'Peter', 
    'Josh', 
    'Jasper'
);

// Array containing ages
$agesArr = array(
    18,
    19,
    25
);

$arrayDesign = array(
    'name' => $namesArr, 
    'age'  => $agesArr
);

/**
 * Combines given array design into one grouped by keys.
 * Example Input:
 *      $design => array(
 *          'name' => array('Name1', 'Name2'), 
 *          'age'  => array(10, 20)
 *      );
 * Example Output:
 *      $output => array(
 *          0 => array(
 *              'name' => 'Name1', 
 *              'age' => 10
 *          ), 
 *          1 => array(
 *              'name' => 'Name2', 
 *              'age' => 20
 *          )
 *      );
 * 
 * @param Array $arrayDesign
 * 
 * @return Array combined array
 */
function combineArraysByKeys($arrayDesign) {

    // Holds results
    $results = array();

    // Get size of first element from the design, so we'll know the size of rest elements.
    $designElementSize = count($arrayDesign[array_keys($arrayDesign)[0]]);

    // Count from-to elements
    for($c = 0; $c < $designElementSize; $c++) {

        // Define array as part of results to be added after population
        $arrayPart = array();

        // Loop thru all keys and get values
        foreach(array_keys($arrayDesign) as $key) {

            // Assign value to key
            $arrayPart[$key] = $arrayDesign[$key][$c];
        }

        // Add to results array
        $results[] = $arrayPart;
    }

    return $results;
}

$result = combineArraysByKeys($arrayDesign);

echo "<PRE>";
print_r($result);
die();
```